# jQuery remove class determined by previous user interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML element `select#options` which when selecting one of the options will dynamically add classes to the element `div#container`, but I need to delete the class that was previously added to this element and then add the new class according to the selected option.

If they realize, the classes are always added but, but they are still the same ones that were added.

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).on('change', 'select#options', function(){
    
    var option_selected = $(this).val();
    $('#container').addClass(option_selected);
    $('#container').html(option_selected);
    console.log($('#container').attr('class'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="options" id="options">
 <option value="" selected>Select</option>
 <option value="style1">Style 1</option>
 <option value="style2">Style 2</option>
 <option value="style3">Style 3</option>
 <option value="style4">Style 4</option>
 <option value="style5">Style 5</option>
</select> 

<div id="container" class="container default"></div>
```

Comment: which class you want delete ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a variable to keep track of the last class added, and remove it before adding the new one.

```js
var previous_class = "";

$(function(){
  $(document).on('change', 'select#options', function(){
    
    var option_selected = $(this).val();
    $('#container').removeClass(previous_class);
    previous_class = option_selected;
    $('#container').addClass(option_selected);
    $('#container').html(option_selected);
    console.log($('#container').attr('class'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="options" id="options">
 <option value="" selected>Select</option>
 <option value="style1">Style 1</option>
 <option value="style2">Style 2</option>
 <option value="style3">Style 3</option>
 <option value="style4">Style 4</option>
 <option value="style5">Style 5</option>
</select> 

<div id="container" class="container default"></div>
```

If you need to keep track of more than one selector/label, then you can store the previous class as a data attribute of the div.

```
$('#container').data('previous-class', option_selected);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove class. Either keep a record of the name you added or just remove them all if that's what you want.

https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Comment: I know this function, but how can I get the class added before or delete a class or all classes omitting some.

Comment: If you're looking to add class 'X', then at some point add class 'Y' but remove 'X', save the class when you add it in something like 'data-lastclass'. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Learningandsharing check my answer above, if you want to remove specific classes use `removeClass()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a fresh class each time, you can do it by setting the class **attribute** for your div.

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).on('change', 'select#options', function(){
    
    var option_selected = $(this).val();
    $('#container').attr("class", option_selected);
    $('#container').html(option_selected);
    console.log($('#container').attr('class'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="options" id="options">
 <option value="" selected>Select</option>
 <option value="style1">Style 1</option>
 <option value="style2">Style 2</option>
 <option value="style3">Style 3</option>
 <option value="style4">Style 4</option>
 <option value="style5">Style 5</option>
</select> 

<div id="container" class="container default"></div>
```